# pgfplots Udefined control sequence \Generic Error

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot a graph importing my data from a .csv file but I can't get the result I want, every time it crashes. I tried the same code with similar .csv files and it works so I am getting stuck on this problem.
Here the content of my "week1.csv" file I am trying to plot:

```
time;sensor;simulated
1;19.5;19.49464548
2;19;19.17700791
3;18.8;18.86136048
4;18.6;18.54761463
5;18.4;18.23280342
6;18.3;17.92352567
7;18.1;17.62078638
8;18;17.31792151
9;18.2;17.01524028
10;18.4;16.72588304
11;18.1;17.11651363
12;17.9;17.77873087
13;17.9;18.15327621
14;17.8;17.95555478
15;17.7;17.74795501
16;17.6;17.52594093
17;17.5;17.29089669
18;17.5;17.04891717
19;19;16.81216107
20;18.9;17.27730302
21;19.1;17.94622146
22;19.1;18.59686856
23;19;18.98953883
24;19.1;18.99968524
25;18.6;18.77590152
26;18.1;18.53879784
27;17.9;18.31538976
28;17.7;18.10095345
29;17.6;17.90183671
30;17.4;17.70783841
31;17.3;17.52240945
32;17.2;17.34032281
33;17.9;17.74491767
34;18.2;18.17176908
35;17.7;17.99280995
36;17.5;17.84541031
37;17.7;17.71454988
38;17.5;17.60762704
39;17.5;17.51463032
40;17.3;17.38723956
41;17.1;17.24170862
42;17.2;17.44086405
43;19;18.16053655
44;18.9;18.85514275
45;19;18.99956759
46;19;18.99635606
47;19.1;18.99870573
48;19.1;18.99918397
```

And here my code:

```
\documentclass[pdftex, a4paper, 11pt]{book}

\input{content/packages&settings}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={font={\scriptsize}}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,1.03)},anchor=south}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
font={\scriptsize}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  height=3.5cm,
  width=11cm,
  axis y line=left,
  axis line style=-,
  y axis line style=-,
  tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
  label style={font=\scriptsize},
  title style={font=\scriptsize},
  xlabel={Time [days]},
  ylabel={Power [kW]},
  legend columns = 2,
  legend style={draw=none, fill=none}
  ]
\addplot[color=black, mark=] table[col sep=semicolon,trim cells=true, 
y=sensor]{data/week1.csv};
\addlegendentry{Measured}
\addplot[color=red, mark=] table[col sep=semicolon,trim cells=true, 
y=simulated] {data/week1.csv};
\addlegendentry{Simulated}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Worse mismatches between the power production as measured and 
forecasted during week 22 of 2016. Data taken from , DSO Régie de Wavre.}
\label{fig:ch7-1-pv}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Where the package&settings.tex file I am importing is the following:

```
\usepackage{notes}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, fit}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Dark2}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

% UT Style
\usepackage{sectsty,textcase}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{notes}
\usepackage{watermark}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{todonotes}  %needed for todos
\usepackage{siunitx}    %for Celsius degree symbol


% New Commands
\newcommand{\tbi}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\imp}[1]{\underline{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\let\svitem\item%
\def\mybox#1{\makebox[2cm][l]{\bfseries#1}}
\newenvironment{leftitemize}
{\renewcommand\item[1][$\bullet$]{\svitem[\mybox{##1}]}%
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=\dimexpr2cm+\labelsep]}{\end{itemize}}

% Plot of graphs
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
```

After compiling this I get multiple Undefined Control Sequence Error but it looks like they are not pointing at the real problem (see image).[image]

Here you can see my .log file:    https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JBDwYsNhxNRvZt6x7B6jIKM7l8mfOAyt

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete MWE, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) When I remove the empty line after `width` the code works perfectly fine for me (with PGFPlots v1.16)

Comment: After width, I had a commented line. Also after removing it it still doesn't compile

Comment: Works perfectly fine here as well. Are you using `pdflatex` to generate the PDF, or `xelatex`/`lualatex`? Can you show the `.log` file?

Comment: I am using     pdflatex I uploaded the     .log file to the main question

Comment: That log is obviously from a bigger document. If you take the code you provided above, then add `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, do you get the same error?

Comment: If I do so, it gives me problem with the "time" element of my .csv file. However, if I delete the "x=time" from my \addplot, then it works. Nevertheless, if I try the same on the big fie it keeps giving me the same problem..

Comment: (What does "problem" mean?) That would indicate that part of the problem is with code you haven't shown us, which makes it impossible to answer without more information. You need to take your big document and reduce it to the smallest possible that still reproduces the error (a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)).

Comment: I managed to reduce the document still getting the same error.
I edited the main question, please have a look

Answer (score 2):

After some debugging, I found the problem.
Apparently using the package: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}, was the cause of my problem. I am not totally sure on the reason why this happen but by only removing the package the script works and the image is generated.